# get local file path to play audio files in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm still learning Angular 4, but I'm trying to make a local desktop app with electron and Angular 4. I just want it to play music from locally stored music in our computers but the Input element is giving fake path. 
I'm using it with "Howler.js" but it requires a source in an array. I'm trying to push the location to the the array for it to find and play. 
Any times I could use to do that because I'm not getting anywhere so far.

Comment: Have a look at this https://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio

Comment: For starters look in to 'fs'. Angular 4 will not be able to access the the local file system.